# centralized / distributed sharing

Tags: algorithm, sharing, data-transfer

I would like to make a system whereby users can upload and download files. The system will have a centralized topography but will rely heavily on peers to transfer relevant data through the central node to other peers. Instead of peers holding entire files I would like for them to hold a compressed an encrypted portion of the whole data set.

1. Some client uploads file to server anonymously

   I would like for the client to be able to upload using some sort of NAT (random ip), realizing that the server would not be able to send confirmation packets back to the client. Is ensuring data integrity feasible with a header relaying the total content length, and disregarding the entire upload if there is a mismatch?
2. Server indexes, compresses and splits the data into chunks adding identifying bytes to each chunk, encrypts it, and splits the data over the network while mapping the locations of each chunk.

   The server will also update the file index for peers upon request. As more data is added to the system, I imagine that the compression can become more efficient. I would like to be able to push these new dictionary entries to peers so they can update both their chunks and the decompression system in the client software, without causing overt network strain. If encrypted, the chunks can be large without any client being aware of having part of x file.
3. Some client requests a file

   The central node performs a lookup to determine the location of the chunks within the network and requests these chunks from peers. Once the chunks have been assembled, they are sent (still encrypted and compressed) to the client, who then translates the content into the decompressed file. It would be nice if an encrypted request could be made through a peer and relayed to a server, and onion routed through multiple paths with end-to-end encryption.

In the background, the server will be monitoring the stability and redundancy of the chunks, and if necessary will take on chunks that near extinction, and either hold them in it's own bank or redistribute them over the network if there are willing clients. In this way, the central node can shrink and grow as appropriate.

The goal is to have a network within which any client can upload or download data with no single other peer knowing who has done either, but with free and open access to all.

The system must be able to handle a massive amount of simultaneous connections while managing the peers and data library without loosing it's head.

What would be your optimal implementation?

Edit : Bounty opened.

Over the weekend, I implemented a system that does basically the above, minus part 1. For the upload, I just implemented SSL instead of forging the IP address. The system is weak in several areas. Files are split into 1MB chunks and encrypted, and sent to registered peers at random. The recipient(s) for each chunk are stored in the database. I fear that this will quickly grow too large to be manageable, but I also want to avoid having to flood the network with chunk requests. When a file is requested, the central node informs peers possessing the chunks that they need to send the chunks to x client (in p2p mode) or to the server (in direct mode), which then transfers the file down. The system is just one big hack, and written in ruby, which I imagine is not really up to the task. For the rewrite, I am considering using C++ with Boost.Asio.

I am looking for general suggestions regarding architecture and system design. I am not at all attached to my current implementation.

Current Topography

Server Handling client uploads,indexing, and content propagation
Server Handling client requests
Client for upload files and requesting files
Client Server accepting chunks and requests

I would like for the client not to have to have a persistent server running, but I can't think of a good way around it.

I would post some of the code but its embarassing. Thanks. Please ask any questions, the basic idea is to have a decent anonymous file sharing model combining the strengths of both the distributed and centralized model of content distribution. If you have a totally different idea, please feel free to post it if you want.

Comment: I would like to offer bounty but I can't seem to find the button?

Comment: Oh, have to wait 2 days. 500 bounty going up then, if anyone would like to help in advance.

Comment: You do know that you're asking for a top level design for a complicated system right ? That usually cost more than points.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to do non-bidirectional data transfer because the server will not ack.  But you also want the server to push out data to these clients?

Comment: @Suroot for upload yes, one directional, download will be handled differently.

Comment: @Yochai Timmer - I know, and I'm not looking for a white paper on distributed data transfer and encryption, just looking honestly for ideas and considerations from other developers. If I could award beers, I would.

Comment: Check out the UDP protocol; you would need to implement your own checksum/length protocol (i.e. first 8 bytes are the length in bytes that are to follow.  next 32 bytes are a checksum of the payload.  Collect the data for the length; then perform the checksum to see if it matched.

Answer (score 6):

> I would like for the client to be able
>   to upload using some sort of NAT
>   (random ip), realizing that the server
>   would not be able to send confirmation
>   packets back to the client. Is
>   ensuring data integrity feasible with
>   a header relaying the total content
>   length, and disregarding the entire
>   upload if there is a mismatch?

No, that's not feasible. If your packets are 1500 bytes, and you have 0.1% packetloss, the chance of a one megabyte file being uploaded without any lost packets is .999 ^ (1048576 / 1500) = 0.497, or under 50%. Further, it's not clear how the client would even know if the upload succeeded if the server has no way to send acknowledgements back to the client.

One way around the acknowledgement issue would be to use a [rateless code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fountain_code), which allows the client to compute and send an effectively infinite number of unique blocks, such that any sufficiently large subset is enough to reconstruct the original file. This adds a large amount of complexity to both the client and server, however, and still requires some way to notify the client that the server has received the complete file.

It seems to me you're confusing several issues here. If your system has a centralized component to which your clients upload, why do you need to do NAT traversal at all?

For parts two and three of your question, you probably want to research [Distributed Hash Tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_hash_table) and content-based addressing (but with major caveats explained [here](http://valerieaurora.org/monkey.html)). Preventing the nodes from knowing the content of the files they store could be accomplished by, for example, encrypting the files with the first hash of their content, and storing them keyed by the second hash - this means that anyone who knows the hash of the file can retrieve it, but clients cannot decrypt the files they host.

In general, I would suggest starting by writing down a solid list of goals for the system you're designing, then looking for an architecture that suits those goals. In contrast, it sounds like you have some implicit goals, and have already picked a basic system architecture - which may not suit your full goals - based on that.

Comment: thank you kindly for your reply here. Based on your first remark, I have decided to nix the anonymous upload and instead implement SSL. Over the weekend I implemented a working system that splits the upload into chunks and encrypts each byte. The file is transferred to peers selected randomly (need a better algorithm here) from a list of registered peers and each chunk is mapped to the database (inefficient?). When a file is requested by a client, the server requests the chunks from the peers on the list, combines and decrypts, and then sends. It's working, but it isn't pretty.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for arriving late at the generous 500 reputation party, but even if i am too late i would like to add a little of my research to your discussion.

Yes such a system would be nice, like **Bittorrent** but with **encrypted** files and hashes of the un-encrypted data. In BT you can add encrypted files of course, but then the hashes would be of the encrypted data and thus not possible to identify retrieval-sources without a centralized queryKey->hashCollection storage, i.e. a server that does all the work of identifying package-sources for every client. A similar system was attempted by **Freenet** (http://freenetproject.org/), although more limited than what you attempt.

For the **NAT** consideration let's first look at:   aClient -> yourServer   (and aClient->aClient later)

For the communication between a client and your server the NATs (and firewalls that shield the clients) are not an issue! Since the clients initiate the connection to your server (which has either fixed ip-address or a dns-entry (or dyndns)) you dont even have to think about NATs, the server can respond without an issue since, even if multiple clients are behind a single corporate firewall the firewall (its NAT) will look up with which client the server wants to communicate and forwards accordingly (without you having to tell it to).

Now the "hard" part: **client -> client** communication through firewalls/NAT: The central technique you can use is **hole-punching** (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching). It works so well it is what Skype uses (from one client behind a corporate firewall to another; (if it does not succeed it uses a mirroring-server)). For this you need both clients to know the address of the other and then shoot some packets at eachother so how do they get eachother's addresses?: Your server gives the addresses to the clients (this requires that not only a requester but also every distributer open a connection to your server periodically).

Before i talk about your concern about data-integrity, the general distinction between **packages** and **packets** you could (and i guess should) make:

You just have to consider that you can separate between your (application-domain) packages (large) and the packets used for internet-transmission (small, limited by MTU among other things): It would be slow to have both be the same size, the size of a maximum tcp/ip packet is 576 (minus overhead; take a look here: http://www.comsci.us/datacom/ippacket.html ); you could do some experiments about what a good size for your packages is, my best guess is that 50k-1M would all be fine (but profiling would optimize that since we dont if most of the files you want to distribute are large or small).

About **data-integrity**: For your packages you definitely need a hash, i would recommend to directly take a **cryptographic** hash since this prevents tampering (in addition to corruption); you dont need to record the size of the packages since if the hash is faulty you have to re-transmit the package anyways. Bear in mind, that this kind of package-corruption is not very frequent if you use **TCP/IP** for packet transmission (yes, you can use TCP/IP even in your scenario), it automatically corrects (re-requests) transmission-errors. The huge advantage is that all computers and routers in between know TCP/IP and check for corruption **automatically** on every step in between the source and destination computer, so they can re-request the packet themselves which makes it very **fast**. They would not know about a packet-integrity-protocol you implement yourself so with that custom protocol the packet has to arrive at the destination before the re-request can even start.

For the next thought let's call the client which publishes a file the **"publisher"**, i know this is kind of obvious, however it is important to distinguish this from "uploader", since the client does not need to upload the file to your server (just some info about it, see below).

Implementing the central indexing-server should be no problem, the problem would be that you plan to have it **encrypt** all the files itself instead of making the publisher do that heavy work (good encryption is very heavy lifting). The only problem with having the publisher (not the server) encrypt the data is, that you have to trust the publisher to give you reasonable search-keywords: theoretically it could give you a very attractive search-keyword every client desires together with a reference to **bogus data** (encrypted data is hard to distinguish from random data). But the solution to this problem is **crowd-sourcing**: make your server store a user-rating so downloaders can vote on files. The implementation of the table you need could be a regular-old **hash-table** of individual search-keywords to client-ID's (see below) who have that package. The publisher is at first the only client that holds the data, but every client that downloaded at least one of the packages should then be added to the hash-table's entry, so if the publisher goes offline and every package has been downloaded by at least one client everything continues working. Now critically the mapping **client-ID->IP-Addresses** is non-trivial because it changes often (e.g. every 24 hours for many clients); to compensate, you have to have another table on your server that makes this mapping and make the clients contact the server periodically (e.g. every hour) to tell it its IP-address. I would recommend using a crypto-hash for client-ID's so that it is impossible for one client to trash this table by telling you fake ID's.

For any questions and criticism, please comment.

Comment: thank you for this. there is so much here to consider, and several major ideas here that I had not even considered yet. Still going through it and researching stuff, but I'll be back to comment in a bit, just wanted to say thanks for now.

Comment: thank you very much. i appreciate it. if any questions please ask

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure having one central point of attack (the central server) is a very good idea. That of course depends on the kind of problems you want to be able to handle. It also limits your scalability a lot